# Binary mode in HTTP?

Tags: http, networking, binary

Until today I thought that HTTP is a pure text-based protocol.

Now I go to Telnet in Windows and type:

```
telnet reactos.org 80

GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.0
```

press `Enter` twice and see following:

[image: Strange HTTP output]

This is definitely not Base64.

Does HTTP really support binary transfer? I couldn't find any document about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The HTTP protocol is text-based, but the message body is defined by whatever `Content-Type` is specified in the headers. In your case the `Content-Type` is `image/x-icon`, which is a binary format.

Also note that encoding and the protocol being text-based are unrelated. Base-64 is only required when the encoding is ASCII. The default `Content-Encoding` is `identity` (no compression, no modification). With another `Content-Encoding`, you would get binary data in the body even for text `Content-Type`:s as they would be compressed.